# How can I improve the following C implementation of a program checking if a number is prime?

Tags: c, multithreading, primes

As a programming exercise I tried to write a program which exploited threads in order to have a faster computation of whether a number is prime or not.
My idea was to subdivide the number in P intervals where P is passed as a parameter on the command line, then evaluate an interval inside each thread. 
The problem here is that I have to evaluate every odd number inside the interval and this takes a lot of time to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int prime = 1; // flag for detecting non-prime numbers
            // numbers are prime until a divisor is found

struct args {
   long long start; // start of the subset of the interval
   long long end; // end of the subset of the interval
   long long N; // input number
};

void * runner (void *arg); 
struct args * allocate_struct ( int P );
pthread_t * allocate_tids ( int P );

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int P; // number of threads
    long long N; // number to check
    pthread_t *tids;
    struct args *args_array;
    long long q; // quotient
    int i;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Wrong number of arguments\n");
        printf ("Correct usage: %s <input number> <number of threads to use>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    N = atol(argv[1]); // fetch the input number

    if (N <=0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "The input number must be positive\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    P = atoi(argv[2]); //fetch the number of threads

    if (P <=0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "The number of threads must be positive\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (P > N) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "The number of threads must be smaller than the input number\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    q = (N/2)/(long long)P; // find the width of the intervals

    args_array = allocate_struct ( P );
    tids = allocate_tids ( P );

    /* the following instructions are used to define the sub-intervals among the P threads */
    args_array[0].start = 2;
    args_array[0].end = args_array[0].start+q;
    args_array[0].N = N;


for (i = 1; i < P; i += 1)
{
        args_array[i].start = args_array[i-1].end+1;
        args_array[i].end = args_array[i].start+q;
        args_array[i].N = N;
}

    /* threads are created and start running */
    for (i = 0; i < P; i += 1)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, runner, (void *) &args_array[i]))
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Error during creation of a thread\n");
            exit(1);
        }   
    }

    /* the main thread waits the end of the runner threads */
    for (i = 0; i < P; i += 1)
    {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }

    if (prime == 1)
    {
        printf("The number is prime.\n");
    } else {
        printf ("The number isn't prime.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void * runner (void * arg) {
    struct args * args;
    long long i;
    args = (struct args *) arg;
for (i = args->start; i < args->end && prime != 0; i += 1) // 
{
    if ((args->N % i) == 0 && (args->N != i))
        {
            prime = 0;
            printf("%lld is a divisor\n", i);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

pthread_t * allocate_tids ( int P ){
    pthread_t *np_t;

    np_t = (pthread_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_t ) * P);

    if (np_t == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error in allocation\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return np_t;
}

struct args * allocate_struct ( int P ) {
    struct args *np_s;

    np_s = (struct args *) malloc (sizeof (struct args) * P);

    if (np_s == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error in allocation\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return np_s;
}
```

As I said, the result was pretty poor. I went back to a single thread idea and came up with the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
long long number;
long long i;
int prime = 1;

number = atol(argv[1]); 

if (number < 1) {
    printf("The number must be positive.\n");
    exit(1);
}

if (number == 2) 
{   
    prime = 1;
    i = 2;
}

else if (number == 3)
{ 
    i = 3;
    prime = 1;
}
else if (number % 2 == 0)
{
    i = 2;
    prime = 0;
}
else
{
    for ( i = 3; i <= number/i; i+=2 ) {
        if  (number%i == 0) { 
            prime = 0;
            break;
        } 
    }
}

if (prime) {
    printf("The number %lld is prime.\n", number);
} else {
    printf("The number %lld is not prime, its first divisor is %lld\n", number, i);
}

printf("Loop ended at iteration %lld\n", i);

return 0;

}
```

After fixing all the issues there were in the first program, it works and takes about 10 seconds with 1 thread/5 seconds with 4 to check the same number as the one below (which takes tens of milliseconds).

As a curiosity, can I further improve the second solution? How?

Also, I am not that experienced with threads so I probably made mistakes in both creation and usage, please do point them out.

Comment: The code doesn't even work to begin with. Take the prime number 5 as input. `i <= number/i` -> `3 <= 5/3` -> `3 <= 1`. For loop will not execute.

Comment: @lurker Just because it is on-topic there doesn't make it off-topic here, read the help.

Comment: How many threads did you ask for?  Asking for more threads than you have cores will hurt performance.  I suspect the worst of your performance problem was sharing "prime" between threads.  That means it can't be optimized away.  You can probably improve things by having an outer loop which steps by `i+=2000` (and which checks `prime`), and then an inner loop which checks values between i, i+2,...i+1998.

Comment: @Lundin it works for 5: http://ideone.com/Hr7LD9 You do not want to check the `i == number` case, because it is always true. Every other case is checked, it is not 2, 3 or an even number.

Comment: @Lundin: It works absolutely fine for 5 and 7, because the code checks whether the number is divisible by two, and numbers (other than 1 and 2) less than 3^2 = 9 are primes if they are not even.

Comment: Didn't see that `prime` was initialized to 1, nevermind...

Comment: @MartinBonner I tried using 1, 2, 3, 4 threads, I don't have more cores than that. The code was not working, now it should work as intended (it actually did work for very large numbers but I didn't try it with smaller ones) but it's still slower than the second program.

Answer (score 1):

If you check whether a number is prime or not, you most often find out very quickly that it is composite because it has a small divisor. All but 48/210ths of all integers are divisible by 2, 3, 5 or 7. So for good results you would have to find a way to stop all these threads from wasting CPU time once the first thread has (often very quickly) found a divisor.

Alternatively, you can test for example all divisors up to sqrt (x) / 5 first, then decide that it's unlikely that there is a divisor, and divide the rest of the range into four threads. Estimating your chances of finding a divisor and estimating how much time is wasted would be a nice interesting maths problem.

In reality, you will likely want to check *many* numbers for primality, and you can easily let one thread check one number. Much, much easier to do efficiently.

Comment: When checking many numbers for primality, I guess every thread should use something like the second program I wrote, right?

Answer (score 0):

Sequential version stops at first divisor, but threaded version not. Only the thread finding the divisor exits early, the rest go on until they find another divisor [or not]. The thread finding the first divisor should cancel other (pthread_cancel) to finish.

Comment: That's not true.  The loop is testing `prime` which is a global variable.  As soon as one thread sets it false, the other threads stop.

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers are not prime by definition.  Also, 2 is the only even prime.  Hence you can pre-check a great many numbers simply:

```
if (number <= 1) {
  return false;  // False means not prime.
}

if (number % 2 == 0) {
  return number == 2;  // 2 is the only even prime.
}

// Check for factors of 3, 5, etc.
```

Comment: I check if the number is positive at the very start, in fact I straight terminate the program if it is negative. For some reason I forgot about checking if the number is even or not, thanks for that.